# Getting "Could not modify plist, error" when running the Firebase "Crash" runtime script in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the script mentioned in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios). I tried multiple options but I keep getting the error

**Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUploadToken.plist: Could not modify plist, error: Failed to parse value  with type -json**

Script that I'm using is mentioned below. Please be assured that I have replaced the ***GOOOGLE_APP_ID*** with the proper app id value and ***JSON_FILE*** path to the right value.

```
# Replace this path with the path to the key you just downloaded
JSON_FILE=XXX/ServiceAccount.json

# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:XXX

defaults write com.google.SymbolUpload version -integer 1   # creates file if it does not exist
JSON=$(cat "${JSON_FILE}")
/usr/bin/plutil -replace "app_${GOOGLE_APP_ID//:/_}" -json "${JSON}" "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload.plist"
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym
```

Any help/suggestions on this question would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you verify that the ServiceAccount.json file has valid JSON in it? I believe MacOS ships with json_pp installed, so you can use `json_pp < XXX/ServiceAccount.json` to see if it is malformed.

Comment: @RobertMenke - I checked the ServiceAccount.json and its a valid JSON file. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Switch to manual. Delete everything but the last line, delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*.plist` (both files), and rerun the build. When the prompt appears on the screen, select the JSON file. If that still fails, try downloading the JSON file again; it could be subtly damaged.

Comment: It didn't work. I got the prompt selected the .json file and it gave me the same error "/Users/xxx/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUploadToken.plist: Could not modify plist, error: Failed to parse value  with type -json"

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error. Did you ever find a solution?